# How to combine Criteria with TextCriteria in mongo with spring java driver?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I've a table where I've created text index for a column. Now, I want to make a normal query which has filter on one column and text query on the filtered results.

Through command line I'm able to do it:

```
db.table1.find({provider:"543108bee5ca0167657dc343", $text: { $search: "cake" }})
```

I'm not able to perform the same with **mongo java driver**. Here is my code:

```
Query query = Query.query(
    Criteria.where("provider").in(providerIDs).
    and(TextCriteria.
        forLanguage("en").
        matching(searchString).getKey()));
mongoOperation.find(query, Table1.class);
```

It gives me error: Can't canonicalize query.

Also, how can I apply pagination on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try use `addCriteria()` method

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("provider").in(providerIDs))
  .addCriteria(TextCriteria.forLanguage("en").matching("searchString"));
```